# Phonegap: Using mic

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am developing a phonegap application. I need to turn on the mic of the phone and also access the live audio data chunks captured from the mic, so I can process them.

Is this possible in phonegap? if it is, what's the best way or available plugins?

Answer (score 0):

There is a capture plugin on Cordova.

Capture
Provides access to the device's audio, image, and video capture capabilities.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/media/capture/capture.html

Comment: Yes I know. But does it allow me to access the "live audio chunks" which get passed to through the mic? Basically I do not need to save the audio, instead I need to "listen" to what user says.

Comment: Did you figure our how to do this??